# Running Tomcat7 for https

Tags: java, https, tomcat7

When I changed https for secure connection in server.xml of tomcat 7.0

```
<Connector 
  clientAuth="false" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
  enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
  scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
  SSLCertificateFile="test.cer"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile="test.key" 
  SSLCACertificateFile="CertPath.txt"
  SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

I've an error when running tomcat from IDE

*Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\User.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)*

but there is no error by running tomcat 7.0/bin/tomcat7.exe.

**What wrong in these two?** Please explain me! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need a .key-store file.

```
<Connector port=”443” maxHttpHeaderSize=”8192″
         maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
         enableLookups=”false” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
         acceptCount=”100″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
         **keystoreFile=”/home/Raja/Desktop/Tomcat5/mycert.jks”**
         clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS>
```

check your server.xml file and also refer this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#SSL_and_Tomcat) might be useful to you.

Comment: how to get this .jks file? Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: Refer below links for creating key-store files. http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-5/.                                       http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-ssl#keystore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new key store file and that you can generate by executing this command.

%JAVA_HOME%\bin>keytool.exe -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

and for more clarity see this link [Tomcat SSL problems](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/ssl-problems-td1999892.html). I think this can help you to have better understanding of your problem.