# How to browse with https by IDE?

Tags: java, tomcat, https, server.xml

When we are running **Apache Tomcat from IDE's toolbar**, we **can not browse https**

[image]

but when we are running with **tomcat7.exe** file, it **can browse with https and accept certificate.**

In server.xml, we wrote a connector tag as follow.

```
<Connector 
        clientAuth="true" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
        acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
        keystorePass="123456"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
        SSLCertificateFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\ycassl.cer"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\ycassl.key" 
        SSLCACertificateFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\CertPath.txt"      
        SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
    />
```

What wrong in these two? Please explain me.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895615/running-tomcat7-for-https/11895763#11895763) this could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

These lines of your config file are demanding a client certificate from the user:

```xml
SSLCACertificateFile="CertPath.txt"
SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
```

Your web browser is not presenting a client SSL certificate to the web server and is being rejected. You can configure Chrome to present a user certificate by following [the steps here](http://www.tbs-certificats.com/FAQ/en/installer_certificat_client_google_chrome.html).

I can only assume your executable is configured to present such a client certificate?

Comment: Client certificate is already installed at the browser. When I running with C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat.exe, it can be accepted client certificate and can be browsed with https. But.. if I running with IDE that has tomcat plugin, it can not be accepted client certificate and can not be browsed with https. What wrong in these two. Pleas explain me.

Comment: Does the response from @PeterRader not help? It sounds like you need to ensure consistent settings between two different `server.xml` files. I'm guessing the `SSLCACertificateFile` settings may be different between the two.

Comment: I have one server.xml file from C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf and I did not build tomcat server at IDE. I've been running tomcat from IDE's toolbar.. so, I'd no next server.xml file. I do not know how should I do. If you don't mine, please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: @shariphwar I would suggest you write a comment under Peter Rader's answer for his feedback - I'm guessing he knows more about this area than I do.

Answer (score 0):

You use Mutual-Authentication

but you did not install (or not the correct) certificate into your browser!

Usually at Mutual Authentication the Client must install a certificate into the Webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse, there is a different server.xml located in workspace/Servers/tomcat v*/server.xml

Comment: I have one server.xml file from C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf and I did not build tomcat server at IDE. I've been running tomcat from IDE's toolbar.. so, I'd no next server.xml file. I do not know how should I do. If you don't mine, please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the Toolbar-Button-Dropdown guid you to the run-configuration. What kind of Run-Configuration do you use? "Java Application" or "Maven Build" or "Apache Tomcat"?

Comment: I used Apache Tomcat from IDE's toolbar.