# How to browse https using Tomcat server 7 in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, tomcat, https, connector

When I'm running Tomcat server in Eclipse IDE, I can’t browse https but when I'm running with .exe file, it can browse with https.
In server.xml, we wrote a connecter program as follow.

```
<Connector 
    clientAuth="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8443" minSpareThreads="5"   maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    keystore="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/conf/keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="123456"
    acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    KeyStorePass="123456"
    SSLCertificateFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\test.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\test.key" 
    SSLCACertificateFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\CertPath.txt"
    SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
     />
```

Comment: where is your program? you said connector program.

Comment: Refer this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895615/running-tomcat7-for-https/11895763#11895763

Comment: I think you didnot create  key-store file.

Comment: You getting any exceptions while deploying your application in tomcat console?